# fast conversion of OpenMaya MPoint array to imath V3f array in python

Tags: python, arrays, maya

I need to bridge between two APIs that require the same data in a different format and I'm trying to find some fast way of casting large arrays of one type into the other in python (I know I should do it in c++ but at this stage it is still in python).

one api (maya) returns all points as MPoints with 3 double values as positions and the other (Alembic) wants them as imath V3f.

this for obvious reasons is slow:

```
[imath.V3f(p[0], p[1], p[2]) for p in mfnMesh.getPoints(OpenMaya.MSpace.kObject)]
```

is there any smarter way of doing that?

Answer (score 0):

If the final target can take a stream of values instead of an array, you could convert that list comprehension to a generator expression - that will get you off the hook for allocating the big list, which does take time.

```
gen_ex = (imath.V3f(p[0], p[1], p[2]) for p in mfnMesh.getPoints(OpenMaya.MSpace.kObject))
for pt in gen_ex():
    other_data_structure.add_point(pt.x, pt.y, pt.z)

 #or, if the other accepts an iterable:
 other_data_structure.add_points(*gen_ex)
```

Without trying this under a profiler it's hard to know if it will help.  Have you actually profiled  the existing solution? Are you shore this step is the real slowdown?

Comment: I did use generators wherever possible. Thanks for suggestion. Casting data to V3f object over millions of items is definitely slow. I was hoping for a way to pass data directly without moving it around in the memory. I don't know of any way in python of doing that.

Comment: Unfortunately you probably can't without touching C++ : (